# How can I simulate a thermal printer effect in type?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How can I simulate the noise inside the letters with photoshop?  I think this is thermal printing.

[image]

Comment: Hello Michael, can you tell us more about where you are stuck? Are you trying to find the right kind of noise or trying to find how to limit it to the letters or something else?

Comment: It does look like thermal printing - you'll probably have a better illusion if you also use the right kind of font. This looks like a monospace font.

Comment: @curious, I am stuck on figuring out how to generate random noise texture, which I can apply to image as a mask and get similar result. I've found the font (Hypermarket) which has some worn out edges, but I need also to mask inside.

Comment: I don't have time to take a stab at this but I think [this might be helpful to generate a coarser noise than what Photoshop provides](http://noisepng.com/)

Answer (score 3):

One simple way to create rough noise like that is to turn your design layers into a Smart Object, then you can apply Adobe Camera RAW as a filter, choose the Fx tab, and add grain.  There's a lot of control available in the filter and you can change the grain size and roughness.

As for roughening up the text itself, you can add an outer glow, and an inner glow layer effect, and change the mode to "dissolve". This will give you some extra pixel noise around the letters, and inside the letters.

[image]

Here's an example showing the Smart Object, with Grain applied

[image]

Here's the result, zoomed in slightly to see more of the texture

[image]

Comment: You could also use the paper texture as *Displacement Map* to make it even more realistic.

Comment: @Wolff yeah absolutely.

Comment: Very close, though the particle size/shape is rather varying and not just a pixel. Do you know of any plugin able to generate more complex noise with control over the shape, opacity?

Comment: @Michael Not that I know of. Sorry.

Comment: @BillyKerr No worries, thanks a lot

Comment: @Michael, you can make your own custom noise by combining Camera Raw grain of different *scales*. Also try to manipulate the noise with filters like Gaussian Blur, Unsharp Mask, Maximum, Minimum, Dust & Scratches, Median etc. Layer them with different opacity and so on.